# how can apply routerLinkActive directive to this.router.navigate(...) method in angular?;

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

we can apply routerLinkActive directive along with [routerLink] simply as:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/profile'" routerLinkActive="active"> My Profile </a>
```

of course for tag `<a></a>`. but if we want to navigate for action as bellow:
.ts file:

```js
navigateToMyProfile(): void {
 this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
}
```

And the template is:

<mat-list-item (click)="navigateToMyProfile()">

where we can apply routerLinkActive directive for above method? Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use `mat-list-item` [as an attribute](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#navigation-lists) instead.

> Use `mat-nav-list` tags for navigation lists (i.e. lists that have anchor tags).
>
> Simple navigation lists can use the `mat-list-item` attribute on anchor tag elements directly

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">My Profile</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Is there a way to route components using click event on mat-list-item and apply routerLinkActive?, because we iterated mat-list-item via ngFor and we are in trouble for setting value of routerLink of each iteration. Actually we used click event in iteration of mat-list-items and couch index of each item in navigateItems method to route them.

Comment: Could you please add an example to the original question?